# NodeJs set readline module speed

Tags: node.js

Im reading a text file in NodeJs using readline module.

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('log.txt')
});
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
  console.log(line);
});
lineReader.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Is there any way to set the time of the reading?
For example i want to read each line every 5msec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause the reader stream as soon as you read a line. Then resume it 5ms later. Repeat this till the end of file. Make sure to adjust `highWaterMark` option to a lower value so that the file reader stream doesn't read multiple lines at once.

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('./log.txt',{
    highWaterMark : 10
  })
});

lineReader.on('line', line => {
  lineReader.pause(); // pause reader
  // Resume 5ms later
  setTimeout(()=>{
    lineReader.resume();
  }, 5)
  console.log(line);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use observables to do this.  Here's an example of the kind of buffering I think you want with click events instead of file line events.  Not sure if there's a cleaner way to do it that avoids the setInterval though....

```
let i = 0;
const source = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.querySelector('#container'), 'click')
  .controlled();

var subscription =
  source.subscribe(() => console.log('was clicked ' + i++));

setInterval(() => source.request(1), 500);
```

Here's a fiddle and also a link to docs for rx:

https://jsfiddle.net/w6ewg175/

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/controlled.md